# spring oauth redirect back to original url after getting the access token

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth, oauth-2.0

I have a web app with spring boot backend providing REST APIs and Angular.js front end as a single-page-application.
I'm new to the spring oauth setup so I'm not sure whether I'm doing it the right way.

I have my spring boot app configured as both the resource server as well as the oauth authentication server. Whenever the front end makes an api request that fails with a 401 response, I instructed the web developer to make a POST call to /oauth/token endpoint to get a user token. The request sort of like this:

```
POST /oauth/token HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Authorization: Basic Z3J1Ym1hcmtldDp0dWFuZ291
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

grant_type=password&username=john.doe%40example.com&password=password
```

And the front end will get a user token and is able to sent API requests to protected api end points.

Now imagine a use case where anonymous user adds a bunch of stuff to his/her shopping cart and hit the check out button, which makes an API request to the backend that fails with 401. So user is redirected to the form login our frond end person wrote. When user enters his/her username/password, the UI code makes a POST request to /oauth/token and get a user token back.

Now the problem is that the user's shopping cart is lost as user has been redirected away. We are thinking of having a redirect_url and encode the shopping cart items into the redirect url and redirect to that url after user logs in successfully.

Question is, how do I do that. Doesn't look like the POST request to /oauth/token would take a redirect_url param and sends back a 302 response to that url. Is it solely the front end developer's responsibility to store the shopping cart and proceed when login finishes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `password` flow of the oauth2 spec is definitely not suited for this use case and doesn't support redirect uri. Flows that support redirects are the `authorization code` and `implicit`.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749

Comment: Thanks for confirming.